# Why do compress air cans always seem to avoid mentioning their main use?

Tags: compressor, air-compressor, air, dust, electronics

In the last couple of years, I've finally started buying cans of compressed air to blow out the dust from inside my computer, instead of using my lungs as I have done in all the years past. It feels like my lungs fill up with little dust particles and that doesn't seem very healthy, plus I have the feeling that my breath is not good for the electronics either.

But on every such can of compressed air, and in their product descriptions, they always show images and talk about dusting your keyboards and stuff like that, sometimes casually mentioning "computer components" in the very end.

This makes me feel anxious, as if there are different kinds of compressed air, and the ones I buy are not made to dedust the motherboard and other internal parts.

The prices vary wildly between different cans/stores/brands. Why is that? Are some bad for dedusting the motherboard and whatnot, and are only supposed to be used to dedust keyboards? Who in their right mind wastes such expensive compressed air for cleaning a keyboard?! I use a wet cleaning tissue on my keyboard. Cannot imagine buying cans of compressed air for that. What a waste. Might as well keep buying new keyboards and throwing away the dusty ones at that point?

Comment: It might be because it doesn't seem to be right for 'home improvement'... I'm guessing SuperUser is a better place. Fixed btw, interesting question :)

Comment: The "primary use" is to separate the gullible from their money....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about [DIY Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Move it to SuperUser, it's hardware related.

Comment: A) They have to mention all the uses in some order. I'm not sure how computer components are "casually" mentioned in print on the side of a can, but just because it's the last listed use doesn't mean you _shouldn't_ use it for that. It would say _NOT_ for use... if that were the case. B) If you're spending more on a can of compressed air than you are on a keyboard, you really should be looking for canned air somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Computers usually have small fans inside them.

When you use a can to blow out dust there is a danger that you can over speed the fans and ruin them if you use long bursts of air.

Keyboards and stuff don't have that concern.

You need more care when blowing dust out of a computer and use short bursts and let the fans slow back down, instead of a long burst and keep spinning the fans.  Prices are usually what they think you will pay.

Keyboards you won't damage, but if you damage your fans you get mad at the makers of the can of air.

Comment: Or an easier method: keep your finger on the center of the fan to stop it from spinning in the first place.

Comment: Dammit! I now remember having heard of this advice before... But I had forgotten all about it when I dedusted my computer a couple of weeks ago... So maybe I have damaged the fans now. It seems very strange to me that this can damage them, but I still believe it. I hope I used short enough bursts for this to not have happaned... They could have just mentioned it on the can instead of avoiding the entire application.

Comment: @MiG  A bit harder to do with laptop fans.

Comment: Depends on whether you open it up for dusting or not. And a wooden skewer tends to solve that problem if you don't :)

Comment: Cans of air are almost as bad as ink for printers.  Can probably buy a small air compressor for a few cans of air.

Comment: Yeah, for me the exchange rate was 8 cans for one simple compressor.

Comment: I've always enjoyed giving the fans - case, CPU, GPU a good spin with the air. To my knowledge, I've never had one overspeed and get damaged, not even on my old desktop machine that I just retired after the best part of 10 years of service.

Comment: Think the warning/concern is for the ones that empty a full can on one fan.  Maybe they should not have pretty things to being with.

Comment: @crip659 how many PSI is appropriate then?

Comment: @RibaldEddie  Think it is the amount of time spinning the fan more than PSI.  100 PSI on a locked fan won't hurt, but 10 PSI spinning a free fan for ten minutes, probably not good.  Short bursts less than a second for a free fan.

Comment: @crip659  No, I mean if I use a compressor instead of a can of air, how many PSI should I set my regulator to, to get the best air blast without obliterating anything? What would be a reasonable number to you?

Comment: With a blow gun that has a small opening(almost a point)  don't need much.  Maybe around 30 PSI to start, can always raise PSI if too slow/not working, we talking about dust and not caked on dirt.  Fans should be locked/blocked from turning, if possible.

Comment: @FreeMan - I've never busted a fan spinning it up with my mains-powered air blower… but I can't say the same for if you touch one with the nozzle whilst it's spun up - blades everywhere :/ Agree, though, cans of air are a waste of money. Buy a dedicated blower.

Comment: I've hit the fan blades with the can nozzle while it was spinning. Not a problem. _Could_ there be a problem? Sure. Have I ever had one? No. Maybe I'm just blessed.

Comment: @FreeMan - you get one heck of a lot more spin-up from a mains blower… enough to throw shards of the fan you accidentally touch with the nozzle right across the room. Lesson learned. The actual speed seems to be no issue, just the rapid stop ;)